# Can't get my custom control to serialize from the designer

Tags: c#, winforms, serialization, custom-controls, custom-component

I am building a `custom component`, and it has a `DataTable` as one of the properties.
All is working well, except that I cannot get the `designer` to `serialize` the columns from the DataTable property.

I tried the [solution in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38736645/c-sharp-user-control-design-time-serialization) but it does not solves my problem.

In other words, when I drop this custom component on a form in the designer, and then do the following steps

- fill in the DataBase property
- fill in the SelectText property
- choose the value `true` for the property DoRefreshSchema (it will remain false in the designer because it is only used to trigger the code to populate the DataTable's Columns)

then in the designer, in the property window, I can see all the columns of the DataTable filled as I expect.
[image]

But after a build or closing/opening the form, they are all gone again...

So what am I doing wrong here.

this is the code from the custom control (stripped to only show relevant code)

```
[Serializable]
public partial class gttDataTable : Component, ISerializable
{
    private DataTable _Table = new DataTable();
    private string _SelectText = "";
    private bool _DoRefreshSchema = false;

    public gttDataTable()
    { }

[DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)]        
public DataTable Table
{
    get { return _Table; }
    set { _Table = value; }
}

[Editor("System.ComponentModel.Design.MultilineStringEditor, System.Design, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a", typeof(UITypeEditor))]
public string SelectText
{
    get { return _SelectText; }
    set { _SelectText = value; }
}

public gttDataBase DataBase
{
    get { return _gttDataBase; }
    set { _gttDataBase = value; }
}

    [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)]
public bool DoRefreshSchema
{
    get { return _DoRefreshSchema; }
    set
    {
        _DoRefreshSchema = false;
        if (value)
        {
            RefreshSchema();
            // After this the DataTable has all columns, they are all present in the proporty window of the designer.
            // So I hoped that this code below would tell the designer to serialize the DataTable ,but it does not
            this.GetChangeService().OnComponentChanged(this, null, null, null);
        }
    }
}


public void RefreshSchema()
{
    if (DataBase != null && SelectText != "")
    {
        using (DataTable tempTable = new DataTable())
        {
            // THE Code below fetches the table's schema from the database and returns them as columns in `tempTable` 
            DataBase.FillDataTable(tempTable, Concat("SET FMTONLY ON", Environment.NewLine, SelectText, Environment.NewLine + "SET FMTONLY OFF"));
        }

        // This loop then create's a column in the DataTable property for
        // every column find in tempTable
        foreach (DataColumn col in tempTable.Columns)
        {
            // I would really like these columns to get serialized in 
            // designer.cs
            _Table.Columns.Add(col.ColumnName, col.DataType);
        }
    }
}


// I added own serialization code, because I hoped that this would solve my issue, but it does not

private IComponentChangeService GetChangeService()
{
    return (IComponentChangeService)GetService(typeof(IComponentChangeService));
}

// Implement this method to serialize data. The method is called
// on serialization.
public void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
{
    // Use the AddValue method to specify serialized values.
    info.AddValue("DataBase", DataBase, typeof(gttDataBase));
    info.AddValue("SelectText", SelectText, typeof(string));
    info.AddValue("Table", Table, typeof(DataTable));
}
    
    
// The special constructor is used to deserialize values.
public gttDataTable(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
{
    // Reset the property value using the GetValue method.
    DataBase = (gttDataBase)info.GetValue("DataBase", typeof(gttDataBase));
    SelectText = (string)info.GetValue("SelectText", typeof(string));
    Table = (DataTable)info.GetValue("Table", typeof(DataTable));
}
```

**EDIT**
I tried adding

```
[DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)]
```

to the DataTable property as suggested in a comment, but it did not help

**EDIT 2**

if I add a column manually to the property `Table` and then change something in one it's properties, this column gets serialized and is persistent.
But all the other columns that are added in code are not.
Is there a way to also serialize them ?

**EDIT 3**

**for clarity, the idea is to serialize the columns of the `DataTable` property in designtime into the `Designer.cs` file.

Not at runtime**

Comment: Add `[DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)]` to the DataTable Type Property. -- Don't know about the `gttDataBase` Type.

Comment: @Jimi Thanks for the suggestion, I tried it but it makes no difference

Comment: Works for me, without the `gttDataBase` Property of course, I don't have that Type available. I also don't know what calls `DoRefreshSchema()` and when, so I commented out that, too. Both the DataTable and its Columns are serialized and persisted.

Comment: @Jimi how did you populate the columns of the DataTable ? In my case this is done in code, and this code is triggered by setting the property `DoRefreshSchema` to true. This is also visible in my code.

Comment: @Jimi Please also read my second edit in the question. It works when I add columns in the designer manually, but not when I add them in code

Comment: I just created the Columns. I didn't call `RefreshSchema()` in any way, since, as mentioned, the `gttDataBase` Type is not available here. Also, the problem statement is: *But after a build or closing/opening the form, they are all gone again*. -- How are Columns added in code - hence, at run-time -- supposed to be serialized? Do you mean you want top persist the Columns' content between runs? This is not related to the Designer serialization. -- Columns added to the Designer are persisted even if you don't change any property, they just retain the default data type (string).

Comment: @Jimi First, the columns are added NOT in runtime, but in designtime. This is a custom component to drop on a form in designer. The method RefreshSchema populates the columns by querying the database, and then uses the loop that you can see in my code to add the columns. That's it, there is nothing more to it. I just want the columns to get serialized in the `designer.cs`

Comment: @Jimi I added some comments in the code for `RefreshSchema` Hopefully it is more clear now

Comment: Ok, it's more clear now. I'll give it a look. -- As mentioned, some pieces are missing here (not just the DataBase property Type - whether `tempTable` is actually filled with anything at this time, the `foreach` loop may never run or the collection is empty), the `ISite` change is not handled etc. (maybe somewhere else in the partial class?).

Comment: @Jimi `ISite` ? I have none, and to be honest I don't even know what it is. I am sure however that the code in RefreshSchema runs, otherwise I could not see the columns been populated.

Comment: The serialization, unfortunately, is only applied to the DataTable object; the  `ColumnsCollectionEditor` that handles the `DataTables.Columns` is only serialized by its editor, which is part of Visual Studio's `Designer.Data.Design`. I'm not sure this can be easily replicated in your class. You may have to serialize the Columns you add yourself. Or resort to a different collection that can be read back into a `DataColumn[]` collection when needed.

Comment: @Jimi Not so good news, but thank you for this information, now I at least know I can stop searching for this. Serializing the columns myself seems like the best option in my mind

Comment: *I'm not sure this can be easily replicated in your class* doesn't mean it cannot be done, but you have to replicate the same procedure, probably through a CodeDomSerializer (or a design-time T4 Template, possibly). I'm not sure what to suggest given the recent changes in the Form designers. I may be suggesting something that is not portable anymore or fails miserably. I meant that, since `IComponentChangeService.OnComponentChanging()` and `OnComponentChanged()` are still functional, handling a different type of collection that can be more easily serialized / deserialized may be a decent idea.