# how to execute code after deserializing a custom component?

Tags: c#, winforms, custom-controls, custom-component

I am trying to implement a method that get's called on `deserializing` a `custom component`.
However, the methods marked as `OnDeserializing` and `OnDeserialized` are never called.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18377046/net-deserialisation-with-ondeserializing-and-ondeserialized) question on SO and from the text I conclude that here these method's are being called. So I compared this code with mine.
Also in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization.ondeserializedattribute?view=net-5.0) I cannot see anything that I am missing.

What I need is that when my `custom component` is `deserializing` from the `Designer.cs` on designtime, I can step in and do some extra coding.

So what am I missing here ?

```
[Serializable]
public partial class gttDataTable : Component, ISerializable
{
    private Collection<ConfigColumn> _columns = new Collection<ConfigColumn>();

    public gttDataTable()
    { }

    public gttDataTable(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    { }

    [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)]
    public Collection<ConfigColumn> gttColumns
    {
        get { return _columns; }
        set { _columns = value; }
    }

    [OnDeserializing]
    internal void OnDeserializingMethod(StreamingContext context)
    {
        // this code is never called
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    [OnDeserialized]
    internal void OnDeserializedMethod(StreamingContext context)
    {
        // this code is never called
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        // this code is never called
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
    
    private IComponentChangeService GetChangeService()
    {
        return (IComponentChangeService)GetService(typeof(IComponentChangeService));
    }
}

public class ConfigColumn
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Caption { get; set; }
    public string ColumnName { get; set; }
    public Type DataType { get; set; }
}
```

**EDIT**
For clarity, the problem is that both the internal methods are never called when the custom component is deseriazeling.

**EDIT 2**
I tried making the internal methods public, as suggested, but it makes no difference. They still are not called

**EDIT 3**
I read [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/custom-serialization) and doublechecked that all is the same as in the documetation. In my opinion it is all correct, but still the methods are not called

Comment: Which serializer do you use?

Comment: Try `BinaryFormatter` or `SoapFormatter`.

Comment: I got methods called for the provided code as expected. Both `ing` and `ed` What is the problem ? Did you need help to implement desierialization instead of throwing not implemented ? Did you need to test if the component is in design time and not in run time ? Also you must know that `Collection` is not serializable by default.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't get my custom control to serialize from the designer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65883434/cant-get-my-custom-control-to-serialize-from-the-designer) and [Can't get my custom control to serialize from the designer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65883434/cant-get-my-custom-control-to-serialize-from-the-designer) and [.NET Deserialisation with OnDeserializing and OnDeserialized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18377046/net-deserialisation-with-ondeserializing-and-ondeserialized)

Comment: [Custom serialization](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/standard/serialization/custom-serialization)

Comment: @Rekshino What do you mean ? I guess the serializer from VS ? It's a custom component dropped on a form and the serializing is done on designtime by the editor of VS

Comment: @OlivierRogier The collection is properly serialized, that is not the problem. My problem is exact as in the question, why are the internal methods not called.

Comment: @OlivierRogier The first link in your comment, look at the author of that quetion. It was me. I abandonend that because another SO user informed it would not work like that. The only solution was to serialize the columns to another collection (hence the collection in my question) and then use them after deserializing. My problem is the deserializing methods are not called

Comment: Downvoters please let me know where I can improve this question

Comment: Try to make methods `public` not `internal`

Comment: @Rekshino I tried it, it makes no difference

Comment: @GuidoG No need to be public. I got this code working with `var obj = (gttDataTable)new BinaryFormatter().Deserialize(File.Open("d:\\DataFile.dat", FileMode.Open));`. OnDeserializing and OnDeserialized are called as expected. You need to add more details and code. Just a note, I wanted to write it in my previous comment but forgot: `[Serializable] public class ConfigColumn`.

Comment: @OlivierRogier I do not want to serialize/deserialize to an external file. I need this done in the Designer.cs from VS. What more details do you want, this is the entire code, there is nothing more. The question is actuall simple, I want custom serialization in Designer.cs, I followed the documentation, but the methods are  not called. Why are they not called

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not all serializer take into consideration such attribute as `OnDeserializing` etc. see e.g. [Why does the OnDeserialization not fire for XML Deserialization?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2897166/why-does-the-ondeserialization-not-fire-for-xml-deserialization?noredirect=1&lq=1).
If I'm not mistaken designer does use [`CodeDomSerializer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.design.serialization.codedomserializer?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-5.0).

To make custom serailization you need to derive from `CodeDomSerializer` and decorate the class with [`DesignerSerializerAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.design.serialization.designerserializerattribute?view=net-5.0)

```
[DesignerSerializerAttribute(typeof(YourCustomSerializer), typeof(CodeDomSerializer))]
public partial class gttDataTable : Component
{
}
```

Comment: what should I use for YourCustomSerializer ?

Comment: See the link for CodeDomSerializer there is an example.

Comment: OK I will try this and update when I have results

Comment: I tried it and it seems to have some effect with serialization. I still have to research it more since I now get strange serialization errors like "cannot convert "gttControls.ConfigColumn" to "gttControls.ConfigColumn". But at least I am getting something from the serialization/deserialization now.

Comment: Yes I got it working with the CodeDomSerializer. Thank you so much